# Select IDs from table where col_2 is not null (duplicate id)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that contains the following data

```
ID | Col_2
A  | 'ABC'
A  | 'GHI'
A  | null
B  | 'null'
B  | 'HJH'
B  | 'NBN'
C  | null
```

I have two cases to cater :

Duplicate Ids:
Incase of duplicate ids I only want those IDs which do not have null in col_2
E.g.
Query should return :

```
A  | 'ABC'
A  | 'GHI'
B  | 'HJH'
B  | 'NBN'
```

Non Duplicate Id:
Incase of non duplicate id the query should return result irrespective of the value present in col_2

So the final result of the query should be

```
ID | Col_2
A  | 'ABC'
A  | 'GHI'
B  | 'HJH'
B  | 'NBN'
C  | null
```

I have managed to create the following query where it is fulfilling the duplicate id case not the non duplicate case.

Query :

```
select id,col_2 
from mytable
group by id,col_2
having (sum(case when col_2 is not null then 1 else 0 end) > 0)
```

What changes should be made in the query to cater the non duplicate case also.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Do you really have `NULL` both as `'NULL'` and as a string?

Comment: No, I only have null (not as a string). Its a typo.

Comment: Can you have more than on `null` row?

Comment: No there can be only one null row per Id

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `NULL` is `NULL` and not a string *and* that you have only one `NULL` value per id, you can do something like this:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.col_2 is not null or
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.col_2 is not null);
```

If your `null` values can be duplicated and you want only one row for them, then tweak this to:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.col_2 is not null 
union all
select distinct t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.col_2 is not null);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c651978bcf18e3e0e64994094d0021bf) is a db<>fiddle.

For performance, you want an index on `(id, col_2)`.

If you just want the `col_2` values for each `id`, you can concatenate them on each row:

```
select id, group_concat(col_2)
from t
group by id;
```

Another alternative uses window functions:

```
select t.id, col_2
from (select t.*,
             rank() over (partition by id order by col_2 is not null desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: This is not returning the Non-duplicate id with null value

Comment: @shahmeerarhsad . . . I fixed a typo and added a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Gordon, this query is returning results for a small table. But on the actual database its been running for over 15 mins and has not returned any results yet. 
Other query on the production database is working fine.

Comment: @shahmeerarhsad . . . I added an index recommendation.  That should fix the performance problem.

Comment: Is there a way that I can edit the query i posted in the question description (having clause one) to return the desired result.

Comment: @shahmeerarhsad . . . Aggregation is unnecessary and just adds overhead to the query.

Comment: But I cannot put an index on any of the fields.

Comment: So I think modifying the having query might be the fastest option. No?